# Does applying ice patch to flea bites help heal faster?

Tags: dermatology, cryotherapy, insect-bites, fleas

Applying ice patch is a command remedy against flea bites help heal faster?.

Example http://www.thebugsquad.com/fleas/flea-bites-solutions/ :

> If you have a cold pack that you normally use on sprains or bruises, you can also put that on the area affected by the flea bites. Ice also works fairly well, although its a bit wet for my liking!

Does applying ice patch to flea bites help heal faster, or does it just temporary alleviate the pain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can help heal faster and alleviate symptoms which are interrelated.

[fleabites.net](http://www.fleabites.net/how-long-do-flea-bites-last-and-how-to-heal-them-faster/)

> Applying an ice pack on the site of bite to prevent swelling, itching
>   and soothe the skin.

And based on what the article says:

> you can also use several natural products and home remedies to treat
>   and heal the flea bites on humans faster

[The Naked Scientist. Com](http://www.thenakedscientists.com/HTML/questions/qotw/question/3474/)

This article shows how [reducing swelling](https://www.urmc.rochester.edu/encyclopedia/content.aspx?ContentTypeID=1&ContentID=4483) can increase healing speed.

> Cold slows down blood flow to an injury, thereby reducing pain and
>   swelling. Cold therapy slows circulation, reducing inflammation,
>   muscle spasm, and pain. It should be used if the area is swollen or
>   bruised.